# MWS or 'Product Advertising API' how to tell if a product is 'Add-on-Item'

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

How can I tell via [MWS](https://developer.amazonservices.com/) or [Product Advertising API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html) if an item is marked as 'Add-on-Item'.

such as the following ASIN: [B0002ARYES](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0002ARYES)[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Keepa.com API has this information available: https://keepa.com/#!discuss/t/statistics-object/1308

Probably because they scrape Amazon and not just the API